# exception in the given code(java)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have this test program where I am seeing a NullPointer exception. I need help finding out how to solve it and would like to know the root cause.

```
public class test {

    private static void practice(String[] words) {

        int vowelPosition = 0;
        int consonantPosition = 0;
        char[] vowel = (char[]) null;
        char[] consonant = (char[]) null;

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            int currentWordLength = words[i].length();
            for (int j = 0; j < currentWordLength; j++) {
                if (words[i].charAt(j) == 'a' || words[i].charAt(j) == 'e'
                        || words[i].charAt(j) == 'i'
                        || words[i].charAt(j) == 'o'
                        || words[i].charAt(j) == 'u') {
                    consonant[j] = 'n';
                    vowel[j] = words[i].charAt(j);

                    vowelPosition = j;
                    System.out.println(j + "At this position is "
                            + vowel[vowelPosition]);
                } else {
                    vowel[j] = 'n';
                    consonant[j] = words[i].charAt(j);
                    consonantPosition = j;
                    System.out.println(j + " At this position is "
                            + consonant[consonantPosition]);
                }

            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] words = { "harpreet" };
        practice(words);
    }

}
```

I also tried debugging it and found the inner loop is throwing the exception.

Comment: Can you show us an exact stack trace?

Comment: For future reference, please always provide **stack trace** anytime you ask about errors/exceptions.

Comment: hate this downvoting..!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have assigned:

```
char[] vowel = (char[])null;
```

and you refer :

```
vowel[j] = words[i].charAt(j);
```

Since the `vowel` array is `null`, this is why you get a NPE.

In order to fix it, you need to assign the `vowel` array with a non-null value:

```
char[] vowel = new char[100]; //for example
```

Comment: but I am assigning it values then..!! vowel[j] ;

Comment: Worth mentioning consonant to :)

Comment: @Gurjit you can't **use** the array until you create it. `char[] chars = new char[10];`.

Comment: @Gurjit,your assigning the **element**, not the array. Before assigning a value to the j-th element you need to have defined the size of the array

Comment: @christopher not able to declare it,,,have to initialsize it,,,otherwise giving error..!!

Answer (score 1):

You should allocate memory for vowel and consonant, otherwise they are null. You can do that like this:

```
char[] vowel = (char[])null;
char[] consonant = (char[])null;
```

If you don't know how much memory you should allocate for your variable, you can use ArrayList which could allocate memory automaticly. Replace the two lines above with the lines below:

```
ArrayList<Character> vowel = new ArrayList<Character>();
ArrayList<Character> consonant = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

and add the char into the two lists. You can do like this:

```
consonant.add('n');
vowel.add(words[i].charAt(j));
```

Answer (score 0):

change these two lines

```
char[] vowel = (char[]) null;
char[] consonant = (char[]) null;
```

to

```
char[] vowel=new char[100];
char[] consonant = new char[100];
```

because of intialising these two arrays with null values,you are getting NPE.

Answer (score 0):

The way you init the two arrays is wrong!

```
char[] vowel = (char[])null;
char[] consonant = (char[])null;
```

You have to assign space for vowel and consonant with a non-null value.